Webactity in AzureSynapse doesnot send the records in sync when I make the batchcount in foreach loop as 15 to start parallel thread?
My requirement is I have 3000 records in my DB for each 'custID' I wanted to call webcatity and the response I parse and update in the table by using lookup city there is also a case where I am calling one more tenacity as it depends on the response of first tenacity?
I am facing issues of data mismatch and also it difficult because it takes too much time ??? what could be the optimum solution ???
WebActity1->Lookup (update the table) -> webActity2-> lookup Actity (update tables)
And all of these I am performing under forEachLoop Actity?? first I use lookup where I select cursive from temp_cust_tbl and then I iterate 2000 times to foEach and also pass as restapiurland id I am appending ??
htts://webactity?custid=1234
Does anyone have any idea how to deal with this ??? I also wanted to take the URL from the pipeline parameter as the security checker identifies it as Coverity and needs to remove the hardcode URL from JSON.

If the current iteration in your for-each activity won't depend on previous iteration results, then only use the Parallel execution of for-each activity. Otherwise, it will cause the data mismatch issues as. And, if web activity is updating any API in iterations, it will do the same in all iterations and this might also give data mismatch issue. So, if you are updating any API one by one, then make sure the For-each activity is in a Sequential run.
If it should be parallel, as per the documentation, the default value for the for-each parallel execution batch count is 20 and the maximum is 50. You can give 50 to improve the performance.


I also wanted to take the URL from the pipeline parameter as the security checker identifies it as Coverity and needs to remove the hardcode URL from JSON

You can use Secure string parameter for this. Create a Secure string parameter and give your Static part of the URL htts://webactity?custid= as a default value like below.

Use this parameter and For-each item() or item().cust_id to build your URL.
@concat(json(string(pipeline().parameters.web_url_part)).value,item())


To hide the hardcoded URL in the web activity, you can hide input and output properties of the activities from the logs.

Now, it won't show the hardcoded JSON or URL in the input and output of the activities.

But you can access its output in the further activities using the same ADF dynamic expressions.
